# How to rotate an image on an HTML5 canvas, without rotating the whole canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5, rotation, html-canvas

I want to rotate single sprites on the canvas without rotating the whole canvas.

I also don't want to create a new canvas for each object I have.

Also, it would be interesting to know which solution is then the most performant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> It’s important to note that changing the co-ordinate system with
>   rotate and translate do not affect anything that’s currently drawn
>   into the canvas. **It only affects subsequent drawing actions**.

```
var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180; 
function drawRotatedImage(image, x, y, angle)
{ 
    // save the current co-ordinate system 
    // before we screw with it
    context.save(); 

    // move to the middle of where we want to draw our image
    context.translate(x, y);

    // rotate around that point, converting our 
    // angle from degrees to radians 
    context.rotate(angle * TO_RADIANS);

    // draw it up and to the left by half the width
    // and height of the image 
    context.drawImage(image, -(image.width/2), -(image.height/2));

    // and restore the co-ords to how they were when we began
    context.restore(); 
}
```

Source: http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/

Answer (score 1):

Based on Luis Estada's answer, I created `rotateContext` function to rotate images and other shapes:

````js
const TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180; 

const rotateContext = (context, origin, angle, callback) => {
    // save the current co-ordinate system 
    context.save();

    // move to the origin of our element
    context.translate(origin.x, origin.y);

    // rotate around that point, converting our 
    // angle from degrees to radians 
    context.rotate(angle * TO_RADIANS);

    // restore context to initial position
    context.translate(-origin.x, -origin.y);

    // draw rotated elements
    callback(context);

    // and restore the coords system
    context.restore(); 
}

// ... more code

// draw rotated image
rotateContext(context, rotation.origin, rotation.angle, () => {
    context.drawImage(this.sprite, 0, 0, 225, 225, position.x, position.y, width, height);
});

// ... or

// draw rotated shape
rotateContext(context, rotation.origin, rotation.angle, () => {
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fillRect(position.x, position.y, width, height);
});
```
````

Answer (score -2):

Change the context, place your image, then reset the context by multiplying your first number by -1.

example:

```
    context.rotate(k);
    context.drawImage(img,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j);
    context.rotate(k * -1)
```

Comment: There is a lot that can go wrong with this approach. Floating point inaccuracies can occur even in such seemingly trivial cases, which would then keep accumulating with every drawn image. Better use `context.save()` and `context.restore()` instead.